# Send and recieve (intercept) SMS in Windows Mobile 6

Tags: windows-mobile, sms

I'm developing an application for the [Windows Mobile 6](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Mobile#Windows_Mobile_6) in which it is supposed to capture the [SMS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SMS) with the sender's number and process it. The application also needs to send out SMS to specific numbers as well. What libraries do I utilize to accomplish? Links to tutorials are also needed please.

Update:

Sending SMS: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.windowsmobile.pocketoutlook.smsmessage.send.aspx

Intercepting Messages: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.windowsmobile.pocketoutlook.messageinterception.aspx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To receive an SMS in native code(source can be found [here](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=227549)). This only catches the latest received SMS:

```
#include <sms.h>

struct ReceiveSmsMessage     // Define a structure for storing the
{                           // received data of an SMS message
    TCHAR SmsText[200];      // The TCHAR fields are filled in
    TCHAR SmsPhone[50];      // Once all is ready SmsFlag goes True
    bool SmsFlag;            // It is up to the control thread to
} ReadSms;

DWORD SmsMessageThread (LPVOID lpvoid)
{
// This Threads function is to wait for incoming SMS messages and read them as required
// It simply passes the result to the global ReadSms variable and sets its flag to TRUE
// Further processing of the message data is done by the main control thread

    SMS_ADDRESS smsaDestination;
    TEXT_PROVIDER_SPECIFIC_DATA tpsd;

    while(TRUE)
    {
        HANDLE hRead = CreateEvent (NULL, FALSE, FALSE, NULL);
        // Open an SMS Handle
        HRESULT hr = SmsOpen (SMS_MSGTYPE_TEXT, SMS_MODE_RECEIVE, 
                          &smshHandle, &hRead);
        if (hr != ERROR_SUCCESS)
        {
            MessageBox (NULL, TEXT(
                "Unable to get an SMS Read Handle. Please do a warm reset and try again."), 
                TEXT("Error"), MB_OK);
            return 0;
        }

        // Wait for message to come in.
        int rc = WaitForSingleObject (hRead, INFINITE);
        if (rc != WAIT_OBJECT_0) {
            MessageBox (NULL, TEXT("Failure in SMS WaitForSingleObject"), 
                TEXT("Error"), MB_OK);
            SmsClose (smshHandle);
            return 0;
        }
        memset (&smsaDestination, 0, sizeof (smsaDestination));
        DWORD dwSize, dwRead = 0;

        hr = SmsGetMessageSize (smshHandle, &dwSize);

        char *pMessage = (char *)malloc (dwSize+1);
        memset (&tpsd, 0, sizeof (tpsd));
        hr = SmsReadMessage (smshHandle, NULL, &smsaDestination, NULL,
                         (PBYTE)pMessage, dwSize,
                         (PBYTE)&tpsd, sizeof(TEXT_PROVIDER_SPECIFIC_DATA),
                         &dwRead);
        if ((hr == ERROR_SUCCESS) && (ReadSms.SmsFlag == FALSE))
        {
            //Received a message all OK, so pass the results over to the
            //global variable
            pMessage[dwSize] = 0;   //Terminate the string
            wcscpy(ReadSms.SmsText, (TCHAR*)pMessage);
            wcscpy(ReadSms.SmsPhone, TEXT("+"));    //International Number
            wcscat(ReadSms.SmsPhone, (TCHAR*)smsaDestination.ptsAddress);
            ReadSms.SmsFlag = TRUE;         
        }

        free (pMessage);
        SmsClose (smshHandle);
        CloseHandle(hRead);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

For C# look at [MessageInterceptor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.windowsmobile.pocketoutlook.messageinterception.aspx), though I am not familiar with the method to read the message itself.

You can also download [OpenNetCF SDF 1.4](http://www.opennetcf.com/LinkClick.aspx?fileticket=v0%2fDKsBCQEM%3d&tabid=65&mid=969) source code and fill in the missing functionality of the receive part (it's commented out).