# Windows Mobile intercept notifications

Tags: c#, compact-framework, windows-mobile-6

[I know how to intercept regular SMS messages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1946914/send-and-recieve-intercept-sms-in-windows-mobile-6). But sometimes I get some special SMS notifications. Notifications are treated differently, it seems that the MessageInterceptor is unable to intercept such messages.
Is there a way to intercept those notifications?

**LATER EDIT:**
On some (or all) mobile devices you get these type of messages prompted directly on the screen instead of being only notified that a message has arrived.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you need to do is make use of the InterceptionAction property. This property (which is of type InterceptionAction, an enumeration) takes one of two values: Notify and NotifyAndDelete. You may need to use one of these two for your scenario.

The following links may be helpful for you in this regard:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.windowsmobile.pocketoutlook.messageinterception.interceptionaction.aspx

http://msmvps.com/blogs/donscf/archive/2006/04/03/89053.aspx

Comment: Did you test this with the type of messages I am talking about? I already successfully use Notify and NotifyAndDelete for "normal", "regular" SMS messages. But the problem is that I cannot intercept special notifications with the MessageInterceptor.